# Spring Boot 2 and ResourceServerProperties

Tags: spring-boot

We have Spring Boot Application(version 1.5.8). We tried to check if it's compatible with upcoming Spring Boot 2 release (currently it's M5).

And two classes are missing in spring-boot-autoconfigure dependency(UserInfoTokenServices and ResourceServerProperties).

Are there any replacements of them?

Thanks

Comment: I faced the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Waiting for the upcoming builds.

Answer (score 6):

Try it this. it's helped me with Oauth2 after migration to SpringBoot 2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 release notes

> Functionality from the Spring Security OAuth project is being migrated
>   to core Spring Security. OAuth 2.0 client support has already been
>   added and additional features will be migrated in due course.
>
> If you depend on Spring Security OAuth features that have not yet been
>   migrated you will need to add
>   org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 and
>   configure things manually. If you only need OAuth 2.0 client support
>   you can use the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot 2.0. We’re
>   also continuing to support Spring Boot 1.5 so older applications can
>   continue to use that until an upgrade path is provided.

I think you have to define oauth2 dep, like

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added this dependency (version 5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) but I couldn't find there mentioned classes

Comment: That's OK. But I don't have Spring Cloud in my project. Why should I have to add Spring Cloud dependencies?

Comment: same problem here. I am using Spring Boot 2 M7 and Spring Cloud Finchley M5... I added all 4 dependencies you guys provided but there is no  UserInfoTokenServices class. Any ideas?

Comment: I have strong feeling that ResourceServerProperties class was removed in Spring Boot 2 and OAuth2ClientProperties class should be used instead https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2